# C++ OpenCV equivalent to Matlab imfill?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I have an original image

[image]

if I use `imfill` in Matlab, the result is

[image]

But I use the following code in C++ as an attempt to mimic the `imfill` from Matlab:

```
cv::Mat BW = cv::imread("smallHoles.bmp", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat edgesNeg = BW.clone();
cv::floodFill(edgesNeg, cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Scalar(255));
bitwise_not(edgesNeg, edgesNeg);
cv::Mat filledEdgesOut = (edgesNeg | BW);
cv::imwrite("C:/Users/me/circleCVfill.bmp", filledEdgesOut);
```

the result is that all the black objects, even the black vertical object, gets filled with white pixels, which doesn't match the Matlab result:

[image]

What is the correct C++ OpenCV code to use?

EDIT:

The Matlab code I use:

```
BW=imread('smallHoles.bmp');
BWfill=imfill(BW,'holes');
```

EDIT2:

I also tried the following code

```
cv::Mat circle = cv::imread("smallHoles.bmp", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat contourOutput = circle.clone();
cv::findContours(contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::Mat contourImage(circle.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));
cv::drawContours(contourImage, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(255));
cv::imwrite("C:/Users/me/output.bmp", contourImage);
```

but it also gave just the same result of an all-white image just like the previous C++ code I tried

EDIT3:

I tried

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat contourOutput = circle.clone();
cv::findContours(contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::drawContours(contourOutput, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(255));
cv::imwrite("C:/me/output.bmp", contourOutput);
```

It returns as output the original image with the 4 small black holes that should be filled

Comment: Can you please provide the Matlab code you are using that you would like to mimic? There are many variants of `imfill` - https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html.  Note that you are flood-filling from the seed point of (0, 0) which will fill in the black line on the left---I don't think that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I provided the Matlab code in the EDIT

Comment: I do not want to fill in the black line on the left. I just want the C++ code to give the same result as the Matlab `imfill`

Comment: Does the equivalent of this in CPP work for you? https://github.com/alkasm/cvtools/blob/master/cvtools/matlab.py#L42

Comment: I tried the code in EDIT2. I'm not sure if it's exactly equivalent to your Python code

Comment: Not quite equivalent---you should be drawing onto `contourOutput`, not an all-white image (which is what you initialized `contourImage` to). You don't need the `contourImage` image at all, just the input clone. You should be using the `thickness` parameter in `drawContours()` with a value less than 0 (or just use the `FILLED` line type constant: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf076ef45de481ac96e0ab3dc2c29a777), you're currently letting OpenCV use the default of 1. I think this would be equivalent: https://gist.github.com/alkasm/e27e410cd188e6080b9a25c291dd4275

Comment: Your third edit does not include my suggestion re: thickness. See the code I linked to in the gist.

Answer (score 0):

In trying your EDIT3:

```
cv::Mat circle = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat contourOutput = circle.clone();
cv::findContours(contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::drawContours(contourOutput, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(255));
cv::imwrite("output.bmp", contourOutput);
```

I got the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5YBR.png

This is expected. If you check the documentation on the function [drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours), it says

> thickness – Thickness of lines the contours are drawn with. If it is negative (for example, thickness=CV_FILLED ), the contour interiors are drawn.

So we can see the desired shapes are taken but the default for drawing is a thickness of one, but you want a negative value (or CV_FILLED) as the next parameter and you should get your desired solution.

I haven't used the floodFill function though, so can't help you there though.